# numpy.apply_along_axis error with Structured arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to use np.apply_along_axis to traverse ndarray

```
    def my_func(a):
        print(a)
```

when `x = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4)]` , I use `np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 1, x)`,it's ok.

while `x =np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4)], dtype=[('foo', 'i8'), ('bar', 'f4')])`,
it return error

```
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in apply_along_axis
  File "~\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 361, in apply_along_axis
axis = normalize_axis_index(axis, nd)
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

how can i solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the shape of the two `x`?

Comment: While you will learn something by solving this issue,you shouldn't waste much time on this `apply...` function.  It isn't fast.

Comment: first (2,2),  second (2, )，i don't know why the second x shape is(2, )， so is there any other way to accelerate

Comment: you can change `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]` to `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`

Comment: @Orbital, your suggestion does produce a (2,2) array, but the values are repeated across the fields.  A list of tuples is the normal input for a structured array.

Comment: You may need to read up on structured arrays.  The fields (2 in this case) do not appear in the shape.  You have a 1d array with 2 fields.  `apply_along_axis` is a convenience function when you have to iterate on several dimensions, with a function that only works with a 1d array, but it does not "accelerate" anything (especially not a `print`).  Put your time into learning real `numpy` methods, rather than looking for a cheap alternative to iteration.